# show Loading animation in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am trying to show a loading animation when a page is taking time to load. I am loading multiple/several user controls depending on user request using Thread. I have tried the following ways

1. `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(LoadSecondPageData), DispatcherPriority.Background);`
   when I am using this it is making my Loading animation freeze until the page loads
2. I also tried `BackgroundWorker` concept Loading animation is working here, but it is not allowing to load the usercontrols and giving an error.

Error: "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."

Comment: are you using dependency injection? do you use to load business data on startup or assemblies itself?

Comment: Yes I load data on startup but I am not using any dependency injection. I retrieve data from an external file and create user controls based on that data on page load

Comment: What is inside the LoadSecondPageData? can you post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the animation on the main UI Thread using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, but any loading of data should happen on a background thread so that the animation doesn't freeze.
When the data is loaded, any final updates that effect dependency properties need to be marshalled onto the UI thread using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` once more.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried BackgroundWorker concept Loading animation is working here, but it is not allowing to load the usercontrols and giving an error.

This is by design, you're not allowed to touch anything on the UI side in your background thread, as it will not be STA.  Instead, bind your progress indicator to properties that the thread could modify, and then the progress indicator will get the update via the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

For example, if you had a `ProgressBar` bound to `ProgressPercentage`, or an indeterminate busy indicator bound to `IsBusy`:

In `XAML`:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="StatusBar"
             Maximum="1" Value="{Binding ProgressPercentage}" />
```

In `Code`:

```
using (var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker())
{
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, ex) =>
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        StatusText = "Pretending to do something...";

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            ProgressPercentage = (i + 1)/100.0D;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ex) =>
    {
        IsBusy = false;
        StatusText = "Export Complete.";
    };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

The background thread will do its work, the UI thread will not block while waiting, and your progress indicator will update as it goes.